# https domain not redirecting to sub domain via htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My htaccess file redirects from the domain name to the sub domain and then ensures it is HTTPS. All works OK expect when HTTPS is used with the domain name:

```
https://example.co.uk              FAILS
https://www.example.co.uk          OK - https://www.example.co.uk  
http://example.co.uk               OK - redirects to https://www.example.co.uk
http://www.example.co.uk           OK - redirects to https://www.example.co.uk
```

The htaccess file looks like this

```
#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https\:\/\/www\.example\.co\.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Perhaps swap the two condition/rule sets around. Also, remove those backslashes from the first rule - you do not need to escape periods there.